# The development board not detect SD card

Tags: sbc

I have problem on the SBC [EM2440-III](http://www.boardcon.com/EM2440-III_SBC/). when I insert sd card 4G or 8G into the board, it not detect sd card. I insert sd card 2G and work OK.
please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

That SBC is almost 10 years old, designed for Windows **CE 6.0**. It most likely cannot support SDHC (Secure Digital High Capacity) cards, or does not support fat32, or both. SDSC (Standard Capacity) and FAT16 were originally designed for 2GB max partition/capacity, later patched to 4GB if your device supported it. SDHC and FAT32 support up to 32GB. SDHC is not backwards compatible with SDSC.